ASP.NET / VB.NET on .NET 4.7.2 : error in Inheriting attributes

I have this beneficiary class that inherits the attributes of Person class but when I use Beneficiary class I get this error:

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you!
I already tried every solution I can find the inherits seems correct, I'm expecting to use the inherit attributes from person using the Beneficiary class

Please don't post just pictures of code. Post the code as text, formatted as code. We can't copy text from pictures. You can post a picture as well, if it adds value, but ALWAYS post the text.

BTW, those are properties, not attributes. Also, don't assign a new object to your variable when you declare it if you're not going to use it. Dim obj As New Beneficiary() is shorthand for Dim obj As Beneficiary = New Beneficiary(). You assign another object to that variable in the very next line so just declare it but don't initialise it. Better still, do initialise it with the actual object you want to use, i.e. Dim obj As Beneficiary = New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of Beneficiary)(body). Don't separate the declaration and initialisation of a variable for no good reason.

If you right-click the name Beneficiary in that second snippet and select 'Go To Definition', does it take you to the first snippet?
